# Is that sort order from subselect guaranteed?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it guaranteed that the sort order from statement's

```
SELECT nr
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS nr FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS nr FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT 3 AS nr FROM dual
);
```

result set is always

```
1
2
3
```

?

Comment: No, use ORDER BY to be sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not guaranteed.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  SQL results sets are also unordered -- unless the code has an explicit `ORDER BY`.

With no `ORDER BY`, you will get the same three rows, but the values could be in any order.  I would strongly recommend that you do the following:

```
SELECT nr
FROM (SELECT 1 AS nr FROM dual
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS nr FROM dual
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 AS nr FROM dual
     ) x
ORDER BY nr;
```

Note that this uses `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`.  `UNION` incurs overhead for removing duplicates -- something not needed for this data.

Answer (score 1):

Use order by -- then it is guaranteed

```
SELECT nr
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS nr FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS nr FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT 3 AS nr FROM dual
)a order by nr
```